# How to filter using regex with grouping in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to filter the following string with some of the words bunched together.

```
country = "Papua New Guinea Marshall Islands Samoa Solomon Islands Tajikistan Uzbekistan Viet Nam"
```

Desired result:

```
["Papua New Guinea", "Marshall Islands", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", "Tajikistan", "Uzbekistan", "Viet Nam"]
```

I've tried:

```
re.findall(r'[\w]+', country)
```

Result:

```
["Papua", "New", "Guinea", "Marshall", "Islands", "Samoa", "Solomon", "Islands", "Tajikistan", "Uzbekistan", "Viet", "Nam"]
```

Can this be done anyhow? Thanks in advance

Comment: You simply can't. There is no pattern that can help you get the result required.

Comment: How would your regex know how many words go in each group?

Comment: Just use an established list of countries, like [here](https://gist.github.com/Keeguon/2310008)

Answer (score -2):

Like people write in the comments: it can not be done. Python doesn't know "Papua New Guinea" is a country, but "Islands Samoa" isn't.